# How to get a list of elements in Appium

Tags: c#, xpath, appium

I am using appium and dot-net-driver.

Im trying to go thru all activity's of an app and get all the elements on every page.

but im unable to find the right way to get a list of all elements.

i tried to use c# regular expressions but with no luck.

if anyone have stumbled upon this issue and can help it will be much appreciated!

what i have tried to do:

```
     public void getElementToFile()
    {
        //var elementsList = driver.FindElementsByXPath("//android.widget");
        var elementsList = driver.FindElementsByClassName("android.widget");
        foreach(var element in elementsList){
            WritingText(element.Text);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
   var elementsList = driver.FindElementsByXPath("//*");
```

Btw i must warn that you shouldnt do this because it will not be efficient at all. You need to use specific xpaths and ID's for any automation. And this has nothing to do with your Language or driver.

Comment: I know. Im working on Languege Verification test i had to get all the elements wich contains text. Obviously, i would use it for evry step i want to take on the test.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes i also faced similar issue when i find by class name. so i used xpath and it always worked. Below is code snippet in java

```
List<MobileElement> allCheckBoxes=driver.findElementsByXPath("//*[@class='android.widget.CheckBox']");

    for (MobileElement mobileElement : allCheckBoxes) {
        System.out.println(mobileElement.getText());
    }
```

Comment: Since im using Appium and dot-net-driver i have to use AppiumWebElement as template. 
Also, i get back a ReadOnlyCollection.
Anyway i tried it but it doesnt seem to work. i never get the elements back. i also tried using all kinds of classes and still i dont get anything.

anyway, i tried using what you wrote like this:

Comment: var allCheckBoxes = driver.FindElementsByXPath("//*[@class='android.widget.Button']");

Comment: updated to use MobileElement instead of WebElement type. That should work for Appium now

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find all elements on the page using the following line.

I Guess the dot-net-driver support of Regax excpressions is limited.
@Shekhar Swami, thanks, your answer was a guidline!

Find all element on current activity using Appium and dot-net-driver:

```
            IList<AppiumWebElement> els6 = driver.FindElementsByXPath("//*");
```